# ObservableCollection - invalid arguments

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a class that is part of a ViewModel layer in a C# WPF application. An error is occurring when creating a new `ObservableCollection` object and assigning it to `this.AllPositions`. The error states that the ObservableCollection has some invalid arguments. The tooltip for ObservableCollection indicates that it has three overloaded constructors.

First one receives no parameters. Second one receives an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>> collection` parameter. Third one receives `List<Dictionary<string,string>> list` parameter. I've tried numerous variations of `_pRepo.GetPositions().AsEnumerable` and `_pRepo.GetPositions().ToList` but can't seem to make the compiler happy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**

`_pRepo.GetPositions()` returns `Systems.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>`, and the exact error is

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>>'

Code:

```
public class MalfunctionInputVM : ViewModelBase 
{
        readonly PositionRepository _pRepo;

        public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>> AllPositions {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public MalfunctionInputVM(PositionRepository pRepo) 
        {
            if (pRepo == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("pRepo");

            _pRepo = pRepo;

            // Invalid arguments error occurs here...
            this.AllPositions = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>(_pRepo.GetPositions());
        }
}
```

Comment: What does `_pRepo.GetPositions()` method return?

Comment: Can you add the exact error message to your question please

Comment: What is the exact exception/compiler error?

Comment: @Nico -  _pRepo.GetPositions() returns Systems.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: @Alex and alu - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'

Comment: @Jagd That was indeed some `MalfunctionInput` ;-)

Comment: IIRC, WPF bindings don't play well with Dictionaries.

Comment: @Will - That's what I discovered in the end. I actually ended up swapping out the dictionary for a model class in my LINQ to SQL data access layer. The binding worked liked a charm at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly like the error message states:

```
ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>(argument);
```

Expects an argument of one of the following types for `argument`:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>
List<Dictionary<string,string>>
```

What you pass it in the constructor is the return value of

```
_pRepo.GetPositions();
```

Which is of type

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

You cannot assign an element as if it was a collection.

If you intended for the dictionary itself to be observable, some `ObservableDictionary` implementations are available if you google for them. If alternatively you do need a list containing multiple dictionaries, and intended for the return value of `_pRepo.GetPositions()` to be the first item in that observable collection, you can do:

```
this.AllPositions = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>(
    new [] {_pRepo.GetPositions() });
```

Answer (score 1):

You said your `GetPositions` method returns `Dictionary<string, string>`. But you need `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>`, i.e., a *list* of dictionaries.

So make an array:

```
new[] { _pRepo.GetPositions() }
```

In context:

```
AllPositions = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>(
    new[] { _pRepo.GetPositions() });
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error posted in the comments your Method `_pRepo.GetPositions()` returns a type of `Dictionary<string, string>`. Now your collection `AllPositions` is a type of `ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>` which means it is essentially a `List` of `Dictionary<string,string>`.

What you are trying to do is convert a `Dictionary` to a list. My guess would be to change your collection type from

`ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>`

to

`ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

this is due to you receiving a single dictionary from your method.